# Ace Editor get value on single line

Tags: javascript, html, ace-editor

I am trying to get value on single line on Ace editor.

According to Ace Editor documentation:

- `gotoLine()`  to navigate to single line
- `getLine()` to get single line
- `getLines()` to get multiple lines

Here is what I tried:

```
var html = ace.edit("html");

html.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/html");
html.setTheme("ace/theme/eclipse");
html.setPrintMarginColumn(false);
html.resize();

var line4 = html.gotoLine(4);
var getfour = html.getLine(4);
var getfoureight = html.getLines(4,8);
```

`gotoLine()` works. `getLine()` and `getLines()` doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what does `doesn't work` mean? What do they return or what errors do they throw? Does `gotoLine(4)` work?

Comment: gotoLine() work.   getLine()  and getLines didnt work

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`getLine` and `getLines` are functions on the session, so you need to call them like

```
var editor = ace.edit("html");
editor.setValue("line0 \n line1 \n line2 \n line3")
editor.session.getLine(2) // returns " line2 "
editor.session.getLines(1, 2) // returns [" line1 ", " line2 "]
```